# Can't get data binding to work properly with vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a vue app.  The test version [is here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quotetest-tfvfn?fontsize=14).  The issue I'm dealing with is the vue constructor in main.js needs to set the properties of the Quote object but is not.

The Quote vue file has this.

```
import card from './components/Card.vue'
import quoteheader from './components/QuoteHeader.vue'

export default{
  data: function(){
    return {
      title: "",
      quotecards: []
    }
  },
    methods: {
        addCard : function(obj){
            this.quotecards.push(
        {
          id: this.quotecards.length + 1,
          title: obj.title
        }
      );
      //console.log(this.quotecards);
        },
    updateCriteria(tmp){
      ///console.log(tmp);
    }
    },
  components: {
    card, quoteheader
  }
}
```

The main.js that fires it all up has this.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: h => h(Quote, {
    props: {
      title: "test",
        quotecards: [
            { id: 0, title: "title 1"},
            { id: 1, title: "title 2"}
        ]
    }
  })
})
```

When the app fires up I am expecting that the quotecards data should be an array of 2 items and the text field in the quote vue file's template field should have the value of "test".  Instead, quotecards length is 0 and the input is empty.

Comment: Please update your question to include the sections of code that you believe are relevant rather than relying on an external link.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

In `main.js` you're passing `title` and `quotecards` as props to the `Quote` component. However, these are not defined as `props` for that component. Instead you've got them defined a local `data`.

Within a component, accessing `data` and `props` is much the same. e.g. `this.title` in your JavaScript or just `title` within a template. However they are very different things. Props are passed in from the parent component whereas `data` is internal state, managed by the component itself.

Generally a component should only make changes to data it owns. So making `quotecards` a prop will cause other problems because you mutate it within `Quote`. The preferred way to handle this is to emit events to inform the parent that `quotecards` needs to change. How exactly the parent does that will depend on the circumstances. If the value is stored as `data` on the parent then it is the owner of that data and can mutate it itself.

Comment: So if the Quote should be the only one to change it's quotecards property, how should I feed that data to the component from the main.js file?